# How to update table in which rows are not exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have two tables. Both are still in use. But I'm going to migrate those data from old table to a newer one. Now the problem is. The old table is still active with a current application. So a new DB needs to update data from the old one. So I need to compare a new table to match the current rows on the old table. My idea is to find what is not exist on the new table and then update it from the old one. So I can only find the way to list what's not on the new table as follow: (t1 is an old table)

```
SELECT t1.pic
FROM my_db.car_pix t1
LEFT JOIN my_v2.car_pix t2 ON t2.name = t1.pix_file
WHERE t2.pix_file IS NULL
```

But I need to update new table with those result found from this query. I dare not to try it because the db is still in use. So please suggest me the best way of doing so.

Regards,

Comment: You dont have MyAdmin or similar?

Answer (score 2):

Try below SQL:

```
UPDATE my_db.car_pix t1
LEFT JOIN my_v2.car_pix t2 ON t2.name = t1.pix_file 
SET COLUMN = 'VALUE'
WHERE t2.pix_file IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

I've got my own solutions based on real story :)

```
insert into my_v2.car_pix (tent_id,prov_id,pix_file,car_type,pix_date)
select tid,pid,pic,car_type,pix_date 
from my_db.car_pix where not my_db.car_pix.pic='my_v2.car_pix.pix_file'
```